# XInclude usage and xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation limitation, workaround?

Tags: xml, xsd, xinclude

First, thank you for being indulgent, I am an XML Schema beginner.

I have build a XML file split up with several includes, using XInclude. I have chosen this method above others because each included XML files can be standalone validated.

As I am working on local file, I didn't defined any namespace and then I use xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute to reference my xsd file.

parameters.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="parameters.xsd">
    <xi:include href="./Transducers/transducers.xml" parse="xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
</Root>
```

parameters.xsd

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="./Transducers/transducers.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Transducers" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Tranducers/transducer.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transducers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./transducers.xsd">
...
</Transducers>
```

I don't put the transducers.xsd file because it doesn't give anymore added value to the problem. Just take into account that the transducer.xml is valid against his schema.

So, when I try to validate parameters.xml I got the following error :

**The 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation' attribute references a schema whose target namespace was already used for validation.**

Error that I can easily understand, but I can not get around in my situation.

What would be the solution in that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one; my approach would be to not use xsi:schemaLocation. I've always thought it was bogus anyway - if you don't trust an XML file to be valid, why should you trust it to tell you where to find its schema?

Comment: Not to use xsi:schemaLocation it means not to use schema, am I right ? Except that I want to use XML Schema to generate C++ binding class to access my data...

Comment: No, it doesn't mean not to use a schema.  It just means using some other means to tell the validator where to pick up the schema.  Most command-line tools provide command-line parameters for specifying schema files to consult; most APIs provide invocation options for specifying schema locations.  Use them.

Comment: Right now I am using XMLSpy to validate my files, could you please recommend me a kind of validator tool that can achieve what you are describing.

Comment: Well the one I know best is my own - Saxon. This allows you to invoke validation either from the command line or from a Java (or .NET) app. You can specify the schema to be used and the source document as separate parameters.